# SQL: Get Products from a category but also must be in another set of categories

Tags: mysql, left-join, group-concat, relational-division

I am currently stuck in a situation. The scenario is this. I have products who may be associated with multiple categories. The data structure is shown below:

```
Products Table:
product_id  name 
1           Lemon
2           Kiwis
3           Cheese
```

Product to Categories Table

```
product_id   category_id
1            1
1            2
1            3
2            1
2            3
3            2
3            4
```

Category Table (not required in query however adding it here to help visualize what is happening)

```
category_id  name
1            Fruit
2            Yellow
3            Round
4            Dairy
```

What I'm struggling with here is that originally I want to get all products that are in the fruit category (category id 1) but I also want to check if a fruit is yellow. Keep in mind that yellow will not be the only filter, sometimes I will want to return yellow and orange fruit, however since cheese is yellow I can't return it since it isn't a fruit. However to make things a bit easier I always know that I am going to look in the fruit category as a base.

The database structure can not change as its an opencart database structure.

Here are my attempts:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p2c2.category_id SEPARATOR ',') as categories 
FROM oc_product_to_category p2c 
LEFT JOIN oc_product p ON (p.product_id = p2c.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_category p2c2 ON (p.product_id = p2c2.product_id) 
WHERE p2c.category_id IN ('1','2')
```

This kind of works except for that fact that it will return Cheese.

Notes: I use Group Concat because at the end of all of this my goal is to return not so much the products that match these categories but based on the filters I want to return another list of categories from the products that match this criteria. So:

Scenario:

Get Products that match category criteria
Return categories of those products.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This type of problem is called *relational division*.

There are two common solutions:

1. First solution strings together the matching categories and compares to a fixed string:

   ```
   SELECT p2c.product_id
   FROM oc_product_to_category p2c
   GROUP BY p2c.product_id
   HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(p2c.category_id SEPARATOR ',' ORDER BY p2c.category_id) = '1,2'
   ```
2. Second solution does a `JOIN` for each required value:

   ```
   SELECT p.product_id 
   FROM oc_product p 
   INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category p2c1 
     ON (p.product_id = p2c1.product_id AND p2c1.category_id = 1) 
   INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category p2c2 
     ON (p.product_id = p2c2.product_id AND p2c2.category_id = 2)
   ```

I cover these solutions in my presentation [SQL Query Patterns, Optimized](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-query-patterns-optimized).  I found in my tests that the join solution is much better for performance.

---

@Tom's suggestion is right, here's what that would look like in a complete query:

```
    SELECT p.product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(p2c3.category_id SEPARATOR ',') AS categories
    FROM oc_product p 
    INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category p2c1 
      ON (p.product_id = p2c1.product_id AND p2c1.category_id = 1) 
    INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category p2c2 
      ON (p.product_id = p2c2.product_id AND p2c2.category_id = 2) 
    INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category p2c3
      ON (p.product_id = p2c3.product_id)
    GROUP BY p.product_id;
```

The `DISTINCT` that @Tom suggests shouldn't be necessary, because your p2c table should have a UNIQUE constraint over (product_id, category_id).

Comment: Hi Bill, firstly thanks for your time, I'd assume these just return products that have these category id's. The second part of the question asks based on the products id returned will I be able to get all the categories of that product?

Comment: ^ In the same query (sry) The reason for this as I have many products and doing this in 2 queries will put lots of strain on the server i believe.

Comment: If I were you, I would take Bill's 2nd solution, add a separate join to the oc_product_to_category table and then change the select to what you have in your query: `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p2c.category_id SEPARATOR ',') as categories`.

Comment: Well, that first solution _requires_ the product to have _no other categories_ then the ones searched (in this case: it must have 'Fruit' and 'Yellow', but _not_ also have 'Sweet' for instance). I have no trouble believing the second one is faster, however, omitting a `WHERE category_id IN(...)` will make the first one even slower, and incorrect.

Comment: Fwiw: if I rewrite the first solution from `GROUP BY p2c.product_id HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(p2c.category_id SEPARATOR ',' ORDER BY p2c.category_id) = '1,2'` to `WHERE p2c.category_id IN (1,2) GROUP BY p2c.product_id HAVING COUNT(p2c.category_id)=2`, it quite consistently scores in relation to the second option (1) better, but random, at `1` category (for which this should not be used of course ;) ), (2) about 9% better at `2` categories (3) about 10% worse at `3` categories (4) about 50% worse at `9` categories, and it trails of there. So yes, the 2nd one is better with multiple categories.