# MySql relational division inner join syntax over 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, relational-division

I have a problem similar to that answered in:
[SQL: Get Products from a category but also must be in another set of categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662603/sql-get-products-from-a-category-but-also-must-be-in-another-set-of-categories)

but I need to include 3 tables (that deals only with 2)

I have three tables: Image, Category and CategoryImage.

Image:
     id     name

```
 1      Fred
 2      Joan
```

CategoryImage
    imageId   categoryId

```
1         10
1         20
1         30
2         15
2         20
2         30
3         10
```

Category
    id        title

```
10        Hiking
15        Walking
20        Family
30        Older
```

The only value being passed into the query is the category title. I'm stuck with this situation since the data is coming via an existing website app.

I want to return the image id for images which are in ALL the categories I'm interested in - i.e., if the user selected 'Hiking', 'Family' and 'Older' then I want to see only image 1.  If the user selected 'Walking' and 'Older' I'd see only image 2.

The sql from the linked question works if I manually plug in the category ID.

```
select  t0.id, t0.name 
from image t0
inner join  CategoryImage t1
    on (t0.Id = t1.imageId AND t1.categoryId = 10)
inner join  CategoryImage t2
       on (t0.Id = t2.imageId AND  t2.categoryID = 20)
inner join  CategoryImage t3
       on (t0.Id = t3.imageId AND  t3.categoryID = 30)
```

How do I expand this correctly to add in the fact that actually all I know is the Category table title value.

Thanks for any help.

liz

Answer (score 0):

simply

```
select  t0.*
from 
    image t0
    join CategoryImage t1 on t0.id = t1.imageId 
    join Category t2 on t1. categoryId = t2.id
where
    t2.id in ( $list_of_id )
```

which

```
$list_of_id = implode(",", $ids);
```

or

```
$list_of_id = '10,20,30';
```

Answer (score 0):

image is a datatype. plz,change the table name image and try this query...

select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id=table2.id inner join table3 on table2.id=table3.id where (condition)

Answer (score 0):

This can be possible if you have the count of your category  names you are using in query like for *'Hiking', 'Family','Older'* count is 3 so you can use below query, `SUM` with the `IN()` expression will give you the count for each image group and in `HAVING` clause you can filter over the results with your condition

```
SELECT t0.id, t0.name ,
SUM(t2.title IN('Hiking', 'Family','Older')) `image_exist`
FROM image t0
INNER JOIN CategoryImage t1
    ON (t0.Id = t1.imageId)
INNER JOIN Category t2 
    ON (t2.id = t1.categoryId)
GROUP BY t0.id
HAVING  image_exist >= 3 ;
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b9668/6)

Same for the second scenario *'Walking' and 'Older'* count is 2 you can do so

```
SELECT t0.id, t0.name ,
SUM(t2.title IN('Walking','Older')) `image_exist`
FROM image t0
INNER JOIN CategoryImage t1
    ON (t0.Id = t1.imageId)
INNER JOIN Category t2 
    ON (t2.id = t1.categoryId)
GROUP BY t0.id
HAVING  image_exist >= 2 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is

select t0.* from images t0 inner join categoryImage t1
on t0.id=t1.ImageID 
where t1.CategoryID in (select  id from Category where name in ('Hiking','Family','Older'))
group by t0.id,t0.name
having count(categoryid)=(select  count(id) from Category where name in ('Hiking','Family','Older'))

select t0.* from images t0 inner join categoryImage t1
on t0.id=t1.ImageID 
where t1.CategoryID in (select  id from Category where name in ('Walking','Older'))
group by t0.id,t0.name
having count(categoryid)=(select  count(id) from Category where name in ('Walking','Older'))